# Deprecated functions in PHP 5.6

Tags: php

Is there a list of deprecated functions in PHP 5.6?
I've tried to find it everywhere, but with no luck.
Does anyone had found it somewhere?

Comment: What's wrong with [this list](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 3):

Here we go http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php

For other releases:
PHP 5.5.x: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php
PHP 7.0.x: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php
PHP 7.1.x: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php